# Basic Flash Question - call a javascript function at end of movie

Tags: javascript, flash

I'm a .net developer who somehow has ended up trying to get some Flash working - this is completely new to me, so please be patient!

I want to display a Flash video in a popup window, and when the video has finished playing, close the window using a javascript function "closeIt":

```
<script>
 function closeIt() {
  alert("About to close...");
  //code to close window here...
 }
</script>
```

How can I achieve this? I have imported a video into Flash (choosing "load external video with playback component"). This is in frame1. I thought that in the second frame I could make a call to ExternalInterface.call("closeIt") in the Actions window. I have tried this, but when I publish and view the flash movie in a web brower, I never see the javascript alert.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

AS3, Option 1:

```
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;

(...)

ExternalInterface.call("closeIt()");
```

AS3, Option 2:

```
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("javascript:closeIt();");
navigateToURL(request, "_self");
```

You need the previously mentioned allowscript access for both methods, too:

```
<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />
```

Comment: you don't need the parens in the ExternalInterface call.

Answer (score 1):

You can call JavaScript functions from flash.

First you would update your OBJECT/EMBED script in the host HTML page to include:

```
<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />
```

Then from your code you can execute JavaScript method calls like:

```
getUrl('javascript:closeIt();');
```

Comment: Thanks. I've added the getUrl syntax to a second frame in my flash, but get the following error when I try to publish: Scene 1, Layer 'Actions', Frame 1, Line 1 1180: Call to a possibly undefined method getUrl.

Comment: By the way, I'm using Flash CS5

Comment: @guido Are you publishing AS2.0 or AS3.0? I believe getUrl is not available in AS3.0.

Comment: I'm using AS3 - let me try a new flash file using AS2

Comment: OK - in AS2, the file can be published. If i insert a new frame after the video, and add getUrl('javascript:alert("hello world");');  ...the alert never appears

Comment: I have now got the alert working in AS2/AS3 -changing a security setting in Adobe Flash Viewer was the solution. However, the alert appears over and over again - no matter how many times you close the box, a new alert box opens. It also appears at the beginning of the movie - not after the movie has finished. Can anyone suggest the cause?

Answer (score 1):

Stick with AS3. You want to use the ExternalInterface class. Class Reference: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html

Example Usage:

```
// import the package
import flash.external.ExternalInterface

// then launch that alert
ExternalInterface.call("closeIt");
```

Also I'd suggest you use firebug http://getfirebug.com to debug the JS part of it.